# Exception caught by image resource service Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///

Tags: firebase, image, flutter

I face this problem when I use network image (highlighted in the picture below) in flutter to get the image but actually the image is displayed but still I have this exception.
can anyone help me please

[image]

Comment: Check the URL and include code-snippet of the Network-image

Comment: how can I do this ?